# Module node browserify error

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I am trying to use the dyson module node (https://github.com/webpro/dyson#installation). But, when i use de command dyson i get this error in my terminal.

```
$ dyson Prueba/
  module.js:491
    throw err;
    ^

  Error: Cannot find module './browserify'
      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:489:15)
      at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:25)
      at Module.require (module.js:517:17)
      at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
      at Object.<anonymous> (......./Prueba/node_modules/sha.js/bin.js:3:18)
      at Module._compile (module.js:573:30)
      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)
      at Module.load (module.js:507:32)
      at tryModuleLoad (module.js:470:12)
      at Function.Module._load (module.js:462:3)
```

Do you know what happens?

Answer (score 2):

You have to install browserify.

```
npm install browserify
```

(or)

```
npm install browserify -g
```

Comment: I had installed it but anyway the termina show me the same error :( Any others ideas?

Comment: can you elaborate why this is happening? @Anbarasu Parthipan